# Orientation and horizontal position control of a bar in 2D

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, pid-control, matlab, simulink

I have a scenario where I have a bar of 0.1 m in length, 10N weight is applied in the center. Two forces are applied on the bar at both ends vertically, right one if 5.1 N and the left one is at changing magnitude, I denoted as F+5 N.

F is a value to be determined with the controller, initially 0. I want to be able to keep the bar facing upwards (upside down is prohibited), and not deviating from x = 0 much by controlling the changing force. F cannot be negative.

Initially system is at rest. After t = 0 system will rotate CCW as expected.

[image: system sketch]

I implemented a basic P controller in Simulink as shown below to get following.
[image][image]

I have several questions related to this:

1. With this system(one input), can I obtain a solution which will keep both horizontal error and orientation error within a certain limit? If so, what kind of controller should I implement?
2. I wanted to add PID controller block of Simulink to tune the gains. However it raised error of 'the system cannot be linearized'. At first I thought this was related to underactuation (since I use only 1 input, but need 3 actually). But now I start to think that it is related to nonlinearity. What is the main reason that prevents non-linearization?
3. If I add 2 more forces, can I use PID for my purpose? Or the system becomes MIMO and I cannot?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is quite a trivial solution to this problem if you take a step-back and look at it from a simple mechanical point of view! There's an open-loop value of $F$ that will perfectly keep $x=0$ and $\theta=0$. Try sticking in $F=0.1N$
2. You are right, the system is nonlinear, but you actually still should be able to keep $x$ marginally stable, even if not properly stable. The reason the bar is flying off to the left is because you have a steady-state error in $\theta$, which luckily you can fix by just adding an integral term. Now, because I don't have access to a MATLAB license I can't test this for you , but I would suggest adding one of these blocks here (+ a gain block) in parallel with you're proportional term. The key is that it should ONLY be feedback from $\theta$.

[image: Integrator block]

I am presuming here that you have tried to add feedback to $x$. If you write out the equations of motions you can see that the control input is multiplied by a function of $\theta$ which may be why MATLAB is having trouble linearising:

$$
m \ddot x = -5.1sin(\theta) - 5sin(\theta) - Fsin(\theta)
$$
$$
m \ddot y = -10 + 5.1cos(\theta) + 5cos(\theta) + Fcos(\theta)
$$
$$
I \ddot \theta = 0.005 - 0.05F
$$

There's a discussion here about what you could do about it [how to handle state space model where states are multiplied by inputs ?](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/516227-how-to-handle-state-space-model-where-stats-are-multiplied-by-inputs). But as I've said earlier, you'll be able to stop $x$ from being completely unstable without even bothering to try and control it.

3. The number of forces isn't the issue here: PID control is a linear feedback law and you will still have to find a way to linearise. If for instance F always pointed vertically, you could eliminate the problem. Otherwise you might look towards numerical methods to sort out the nonlinearity. (see the link!)